# I can not recover my all privileges in PhyMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1045

I am using PhpMyadmin. I canceled some structure privileges of the user root this afternoon and I want to recover these privileges. I always log in to PhpMyAdmin with the user identity of "root". But I get an error message when I attempt to recover my all privileges.

> ```
> Error
>
> SQL query: Edit
>
> GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON * . * TO 'root'@'localhost' WITH GRANT OPTION
> ```
>
> MAX_QUERIES_PER_HOUR 0
>   MAX_CONNECTIONS_PER_HOUR 0
>   MAX_UPDATES_PER_HOUR 0
>   MAX_USER_CONNECTIONS 0 ;
>
> ```
> MySQL said: Documentation
> #1045 - Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
> ```
>
> YES)

What's wrong? How to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you locked your root user out from your database. To fix this you need direct access to the databases server (system'S root / Administrator acocount) and then start the MySQL server using the [--skip-grant-tables](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/server-options.html#option_mysqld_skip-grant-tables) option. Then MySQL won't check the user rights so you can give all rights back to the root user.

Note that you should use the MySQL root account really only when it's needed, daily operations should be delegated to other users to prevent such errors in future.

Comment: How to start the MySQL server using the --skip-grant-tables option?

Comment: Depends on your system ... on Linux systems something like

sudo mysqld --defaults-file=/etc/my.cnf --skip-grant-tables

Might do the trick